# Node.js: Use child_process file descriptor as temporary file for key output in spawning openssl

Tags: node.js, openssl, stdout, child-process, file-descriptor

I am trying to generate a self-signed certificate using `openssl` from a spawned child_process in Node.JS. Because of *factors*, I want both the generated private key and certificate to be output directly to memory (stores as strings in memory) without writing to the filesystem. this is easy enough for the certificate, as simply not specifying the -out command prints the certificate to stdout. However, the key file requires being written to (and subsequently reading from) a file on the filesystem.

```
child_process.spawnSync('openssl',
    ['req', '-newkey', 'rsa:2048', '-nodes', '-keyout', '/dev/fd/3', '-x509', '-days', '365', '-subj', '/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com'],
    { stdio: [null, null, 'ignore', process.stderr ] }).output.map(String)
```

Running the following pipes the privatekey to the stderr of the main process, but does not include that stderr in the 'output' of the spawn command. (I am indifferent as to whether to use spawn or spawnSync sync this process happens at application start.) The certificate is correctly listed in `output[1]` since openssl prints the certificate to stdout. I ignore the default child process' stderr because openssl just prints out useless information on stderr. Note: supplying 'pipe' for the last entry in options.stdio ends out outputting an empy string for the openssl stdout and null for the other 3 outputs.

Am I referring to the file descriptor of the node process incorrectly? Is there additional information I should provide?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You are generating a certificate and piping to output, but you need to write to file?